# Ammo for the Mangler (Wasteland 2)

Tags: wasteland-2

I've found a **Mangler** heavy weapon and I was wondering how does it work? There is no ammo information for this weapon.

Is it a single-use weapon? Or does it have infinite ammo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Mangler is a single-use rocket launcher. It uses the Heavy Weapons skill, but as you noticed, it has no ammo, so you only get to fire it once, and then it's automatically discarded.

Beware when you use it: the Mangler is terrifically damaging in a fairly wide area. Friendly fire.... isn't that friendly.

Comment: Actually it is "terrifically accurate:. You cannot miss when using explosive weapons, you're only limited by line of sight and actual weapon range